# MYSQL Slow Query

Tags: java, mysql, performance

Our Java Application is running very slowly.

This is the case for various reasons, one of the main maybe being that the MySQL code within the application uses two different tables to get this data, doing joins. Is anyone able to advise how this Query could be written better for performance?

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT uniqueId
FROM advertisementmodule
JOIN advertisement ON advertisementmodule.idAdvertisement = advertisement.idAdvertisement
JOIN advertisementschedule ON advertisement.idAdvertisementSchedule = advertisementschedule.idAdvertisementSchedule
JOIN adschedulegroup ON advertisementschedule.idAdScheduleGroup = adschedulegroup.idAdScheduleGroup
WHERE adschedulegroup.publisherCode = 'ABC';

SELECT *
FROM taurustour
JOIN searchthemestaurus
WHERE uniqueId IN (
        '18538'
        ,'17142'
        ,'11248'
        ,'18458'
        )
    AND air IS true;
```

Comment: What does `explain select...` shows for the above query. Share the result into the question.

Comment: ' one of the main reasons maybe' - are you sure? To quote Donald Knuth, 'Premature optimization is the root of all evil.'. Profile the code to be sure you are optimizing what needs to be optimized.  If the delay falls on the query - are the columns you are joining on indexed?

Comment: Which DBMS? sqlserver is not the same thing as mysql.

Comment: Maybe share some more details. Explain the contents and quantity of the tables. Tell us how long the query is taking to run, and how fast it should be.

Comment: your second query does not have a join condition specified.  It will end up as a cross join.

Comment: Please list which of the columns are indexed in the first query. For the second query, give the number of rows in `taurustour` and `searchthemestaurus`. And, as Sean asked before, **please indicate which DBMS you're using**.

Comment: DBMS is MYSQL and Not sqlserver. (this has been removed)

Comment: Further testing actually shows the results come back in 0.016 secs, almost instant, I will put the results in next comment. I think the issue may be the application itself instead of the DB.

Comment: Show us some code, how you're getting it in java a little bit more details will be useful for us to understand what you are really upto?

Comment: So is 0.016s too slow for you? Or are you really optimizing a wrong part of your application as @copeg suggests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which table is`uniqueId` in?

A little more readable:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT uniqueId
    FROM  advertisementmodule AS m 
    JOIN  advertisement AS a
          ON m.idAdvertisement = a.idAdvertisement
    JOIN  advertisementschedule AS s
          ON a.idAdvertisementSchedule = s.idAdvertisementSchedule
    JOIN  adschedulegroup AS g
          ON s.idAdScheduleGroup = g.idAdScheduleGroup
    WHERE  g.publisherCode = 'ABC';
```

Do you have an index *starting* with publisherCode ?